# Left justify output

Tags: string, perl, output

I am working on an assignment where I have to left justify my output text. When I test may program I can't seem to get the output to line up. Also for the GPA if I try to justify the text I lose the 2 decimal point precision. Here is my code

```
#Calculating $semester_gpa
if($credits_taken == 0) {
  exit();
}
my $total = $semester_gpa /= $credits_taken;

#Output formatting
printf ("The student name is: %-6s\n",$user_name);
printf ("Credits taken: %-6s\n", $credits_taken);
printf ("Credits passed: %-6s\n", $credits_passed);
printf ("GPA: %-6s %.2f\n", $total);
```

The output of my program is as follows
[image]

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: It appears your code is left justified. Can you provide a sample of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Are you sure you want to `/=`?

Comment: Your last printf gets just one variable, `$total`, which thus gets formatted as `%-6s` -- and the `%.2f` gets nothing.  Did you forget another variable before `$total`, or should there be no `%-6s`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `printf` if you're trying to left-justify the values, just add spaces in the label strings. By label string I mean e.g. `"Credits taken:       %s\n"` (note the spaces between the `:` and the `%`)

```
$user_name = 'Jogi';
$credits_taken = 13;
$credits_passed = 9;
$semester_gpa = 4.329;

#Calculating $semester_gpa
if($credits_taken == 0) {
  exit();
}
my $total = $semester_gpa /= $credits_taken;

#Output formatting
printf ("The student name is: %s\n", $user_name);
printf ("Credits taken:       %s\n", $credits_taken);
printf ("Credits passed:      %s\n", $credits_passed);
printf ("GPA:                 %.2f\n", $total);
```

Even if you wanted to right-justify, you should still put spaces in the label strings to make the code clear and easy to understand:

```
printf ("The student name is: %10s\n", $user_name);
printf ("Credits taken:       %10s\n", $credits_taken);
printf ("Credits passed:      %10s\n", $credits_passed);
printf ("GPA:                 %10.2f\n", $total);
```

Notice the syntax `%10.2f` to combine right-justify with decimal precision.

To make the width of the justified fields dynamic you can use the special `*` (asterisk) [syntax for printf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

```
$width = 20;
printf ("The student name is: %*s\n", $width, $user_name);
printf ("Credits taken:       %*s\n", $width, $credits_taken);
printf ("Credits passed:      %*s\n", $width, $credits_passed);
printf ("GPA:                 %*.2f\n", $width, $total);
```

You could even make the precision dynamic if you wanted:

```
$width = 20;
$precision = 2;
printf ("GPA:                 %*.*f\n", $width, $precision, $total);
```